# Does node.js support the 'let' statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Does node.js support a let statement something like what's [described on MDN?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)?

```
var x = 8,
    y = 12;

let ( x = 5, y = 10) {
    return x + y;
} //15
```

If not, is there a way to duplicate the functionality with a self-executing anonymous function or something?

And/or is there another js environment that

1. has `let` and and
2. has a REPL, as node does? Rhino?

**EDIT**:

This question was asked quite a while ago. As of now, late 2015, the answer is "Yes, yes it does". Harmony features were included by default in io.js 3.3, and have been recently brought back to node.js with the 4.x release.

Comment: Node.js supports all syntax that is supported by the V8 Javascript Engine (by Google).

Comment: http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/es6/

Comment: @JonathanLonowski BS. See Timothy's answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which environments support let statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083310/which-environments-support-let-statement)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don’t think Node supports `let`, but you can do this:

```
var a = 5;

(function () {
  var a = 6;
  console.log(a); // => 6
})();

console.log(a); // => 5
```

Comment: That's about what I figured. It just reads poorly. I want `let`! *temper tantrum*

Comment: I wonder your snippet proves anything. By creating anonymous function, you created a new scope anyway.

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!   Perfect fix for my problem using objects inside a loop that have callbacks on them. (object gets overwritten before callback does its stuff)  Kudos to you my friend.

Comment: This answer was accepted as a pragmatic solution for 2012, but 'let' is now supported by V8 and Node.

Comment: What about if the problem is in a module I'm using and not my own code? I can't install `ejs` because it contains `let`.

Answer (score 84):

Yes, you can use let within node.js, however you have to run node using the optional --harmony flag. Try the following *test.js*:

```
"use strict"
var x = 8,
    y = 12;

{ let x = 5, y = 10; console.log(x + y); }

console.log(x + y);
```

And then run the file `node --harmony test.js` which results in:

```
15
20
```

I would not recommend using this in an important production application, but the functionality is available now.

Comment: @timothy-strimple could you comment on why this isn't a good idea for production applications?

Comment: @TimothyStimple can you please explain why with 'use strict' works but without not ?

Comment: @ButuzGOL V8 only enables the `let` (and some other features) in ES6 when you're in *strict mode*.

Comment: Also, be sure to spell strict mode, "use strict" not "use-strict" :(

Comment: This now works without `--harmony` tag in latest node.js version.

Comment: @WilfredHughes For future visitors, the `--harmony` option turns on features which aren't stable yet. `let` no longer needs `--harmony`... it's considered stable and can be safely used in production apps now.

Answer (score 34):

This is an old question and the accepted answer is no longer correct.

`let` support was added in Node.js **4.x**.

See [here](http://node.green/#let) for the full version support matrix.

Answer (score 20):

```
node --use_strict --harmony_scoping
```

Comment: This answer applies for actual versions of Node as simple `--harmony` option doesn't work with Node v0.12.4

Comment: What about when installing a module with `npm install`? Is there a `npm --use_strict --harmony_scoping`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Babel transpiler and use `let` as well as many other ES6/ES2015 features.

To use babel:

```
$ npm install --save-dev babel
```

Then in your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "babel-node index.js"
}
```

Inside `index.js`:

```
let foo  = 'bar;
```

Then start the server:

```
$ npm start
```