# Does Node.js support let keyword?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

In Javascript 1.7 the `let` keyword introduces block scope.  This is arguably the most needed feature of Javascript and I was wondering if Node.js supports it.

Part of my difficult in ascertaining this is Node runs Google's V8 engine, which comes from such and such standard and I don't know how these line up with the Javascript x.y version numbers.

Comment: Wouldn't this be **trivial** to test yourself, and in less time than it took to write the question?

Comment: @MattBall I would find out what version of node I happen to be using at the moment - not if it's possible to depend on libraries that are using a different version then blow up, not if there's reasons it's yes but grossly unsafe, etc.

Comment: @MattBall so yes, the answer below is something I would not have found by trying myself.

Comment: This page is currently top of Google for "node.js let keyword", so it might be an idea to lose some of the negativity, particularly with regard to it being a duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the `let` keyword is supported, provided you run Node with the `--harmony` flag. However, I wouldn't recommend using `let` in production software. (by the way, you could have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11326647/339852) via search, before you asked a new question)

Comment: I'm guessing it's poor practice to use in a production application since I can't assume a user of my library is run?
And I actually didn't find that somehow but am happy to close my own question as dupe.

Comment: Yes, and because it's not exactly standard functionality yet.

Comment: what is the scene now. Is Let good to be used in production.

Comment: We are using it in a controlled production environment with babel without issue.  However if it is not a standard yet so you may want to take that into consideration when deciding to use it or not in a production application.