# Eslint does not work on local system

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, eslint

I try to set up eslint for my project. When i run `eslint --init` the following error returns:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli.js:18 
let fs = require("fs"),
^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js:29:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

I have installed eslint with `sudo npm install -g eslint`

Comment: Eslint doesn't work. I'm not doing anything with my own code right now

Comment: Sounds like eslint isn't recognising ES6. Is there an option you can configure for ES6 (or if not, try babel-eslint)?

Comment: I had the same suspicion so i thought I had the wrong version of node installed but that is also up to date (v0.15.2). Babel eslint didn't make a difference..

Comment: What version does `node -v` show you? `v0.15.2` does not seem to be a valid node version.

Comment: Yeah i noticed that too but I installed node by apt-get. Do you think that's the problem?

Comment: Sorry i didn't remember the version number correctly it is :`$ node -v
v0.12.15`

Comment: The current versions of node are `4.4.7` and  `6.3.1`. Node `0.12.x` is from `2015-02-06` and `v0.12.15` is just a bug fix release. So new language features like `let` are either not available in `0.12.x` or require the usage of `'use strict'` and/or the [`--harmony`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284029)  argument. But you really shouldn't use `--harmony` instead  you should install a newer version of node using [Installing Node.js via package manager](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/)

Comment: Thanks! I was updating already after i found that link. That did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I installed node by `sudo apt-get install node`. This installed a version that did not support eslint. After installing NodeJS by running

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

After upgrading from `0.12.15` to `4.4.7` eslint worked!