# Unexpected strict mode reserved word "let"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting this error:

> Unexpected strict mode reserved word

when I am trying to run this code:

```
"use strict";
var
fs = require('fs'),
spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
filename = process.argv[2];

if(!filename){
  throw Error('A File to watch must be specified!');
}
fs.watch(filename,function(){
    let ls = spawn('ls',['-lh',filename]);
    ls.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
});
console.log("now watching " + filename + " for changes.....");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283538/does-node-js-support-the-let-statement

Comment: Why did you change the first `let` to `var` and not the second one ?

Comment: Too bad the wrong answer was chosen in the other question :\

Comment: it worked when i changed let to var , but did't get why the "let" not worked for me

Comment: To elaborate on @dystroy's comment - Timothy Strimple's answer on the page linked by plalx is the [correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11326647/316310).