# Getting ES6 features with node and nvm

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-harmony, nvm

I already had node 0.10.* and I installed nvm, then through nvm I installed 0.11.13 and 0.10 again.

node --version gives back 0.11.13

I try to use some of the ES6 features I read about and nothing I tried works.

I run my script with `node --harmony index.js`

`...args` says `SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

`let x = 5;` also gives an error - `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Where can I find what's currently supported in 0.11.13?

Comment: Are you missing strict mode by chance?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11326647/362536

Comment: @Brad - I was missing that, oops. I added that to the top of the file and now I get a different error - SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word in `let`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead

```
"use strict"
let x = 5;
console.log(x)
```

It will work.

run it like following

```
node --harmony file.js
```

Comment: I now get this after I added "use strict" to the top of the file. SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word

Comment: @Madd0g this error occurs when you run command without `--harmony` flag. Run it with `node --harmony file.js`

Comment: Wow. `node --harmony script.js` is not the same as `node script.js --harmony`

Comment: @Madd0g No, it definitely isn't.  You should have put that in your question.  What you were doing was passing arguments to your Node.js script, not to Node itself.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue and found that I was somehow running node 0.12.7 (I know, right?!). Upgrading to the latest (5.6.0) resolved the issue.