# let keyword not working in Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I am trying to deploy a simple app on heroku. App is using Express js.

I am facing problem when I use `let` keyword in the code. The heroku app page shows the application error image. When I convert **let** to **var** the same page works.

I am unable to understand that. let keyword works fine on my **desktop** but not on **heroku**.

Please help if there is any solution.

This code is not working due to `let`

```
app.post('/adduser',(req,res) => {
    let userdata = req.body.data;
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283538/does-node-js-support-the-let-statement

Comment: @Mark_M, Thanks for you comment. I forgot to update engines:{} in package.json for heroku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let` is a relatively new javascript feature. It was made available to Node starting in version 4. It sounds like you a running an old version of Node on your Heroku server.

This should be a relatively easy fix assuming upgrading doesn't break any existing code:

From [Heroku's docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version):

> Use the engines section of your package.json to specify the version of Node.js to use on Heroku. Drop the ‘v’ to save only the version number:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "description": "a really cool app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.11.1"
  }
}
```